# How to document a closure with LuaDoc?

Tags: lua, luadoc

Suppose I have a function that returns a closure:

```
--- Agent constructor
-- @return A function describing the behavior of the agent
Agent = function(data)
   return function(arg1, arg2, ...) end
end
```

And then I have a variable that receives that closure:

```
SugarAgent = Agent{ metabolism=5, health=3 }
```

Is there a standard way in LuaDoc to document the above construction?

Comment: Can you give an example of what the doc would be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by specifying the doc name and type manually:

```
--- This is a SugarAgent
-- @name SugarAgent
-- @class function
-- @return Some value
SugarAgent = Agent{ metabolism=5, health=3 }
```

See http://keplerproject.github.io/luadoc/manual.html#tags

Comment: I'm actually trying to document the AgentSugar function, but your answer came pretty close to what I'm looking for.

Comment: Sorry, it's actually `@class`, not `@type` (see http://keplerproject.github.io/luadoc/manual.html#tags). Someone tried to edit the post with the correct information, but the edit was rejected because it was 'incorrect.' Sigh.